# Calculate percentage in SQL Select Statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, aggregate-functions

I am new to SQL and am trying to create a query that will show on which day(s) more than 1% of website requests lead to errors.

Example:

- July 29, 2016 — 2.5% error

I'm using a single [table called Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mogc4.png) and the errors are '404' HTTP errors held in the status column. As per the image, the table column headings are: 
    Log(id, time, status, method, ip, path)

I've currently pieced together the below query. I've used a subquery to list all the dates that have one or more errors. In the main query I attempt to calculate each day's error percentage using the sum of log statuses that day

```
SELECT date(log.time), count(log.status) * 100 / subquery1.error_instance AS error FROM
  (SELECT date(log.time), count(log.status) AS error_instance
     FROM log
     WHERE status='404 NOT FOUND'
     GROUP BY log.time
     ORDER BY error_instance desc) subquery1
  JOIN log
     ON date(log.time) = subquery1.date
GROUP BY log.time
ORDER BY error
```

I keep running into the following error

```
Column "subquery1.error_instance" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

**EDIT**: I've added the initial `FROM` to my example code block. Despite missing it from the initial post, it was actually present in my query code, so this wasn't the issue.

Comment: Remove WHERE status='404 NOT FOUND' and use Having  status='404 NOT FOUND' below GROUP BY log.time

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `JOIN` for this.  You can use window functions:

```
SELECT l.* 
FROM (SELECT date(log.time),
             COUNT(*) as num_rows,
             SUM( (status = '404 NOT FOUND')::int) as num_errors,
             AVG( (status = '404 NOT FOUND')::int) as error_ratio
      FROM log l
      WHERE status = '404 NOT FOUND'
      GROUP BY date(log.time)
     ) l
WHERE error_ratio > 0.01
ORDER BY error_ratio DESC;
```

Note that this outputs the result as a ratio between 0 and 1 rather than as a percentage.  I find errors easier to work with.

Comment: This query does work but it doesn't produce the required output. 

1. The num_rows and num_errors is the same in the output. Knowing the data, that's never the case. E.g. of 1000 rows, there will be 1 error max, on a given date
2. The num_errors and error_ratio column contain the same data for each row. I would expect `error_ratio` to be num_rows **divided by** num_errors. 

Thanks for the help so far though.

Comment: @vc74 . . . The second one should have been `AVG()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an aggregate function as well as selecting everything from table.You have to have all the fields that aren't in the aggregate function in the group by.
**To fix, include all the fields from table log in the GROUP BY clause** - instead of just log.time

Answer (score 0):

```
   count(log.status) * 100 / subquery1.error--- This doesn't sound meaningful to me
```

It can be rewritten as:

```
SELECT date(log.time), count(log.status) * 100 / subquery1.error_instance AS error FROM
      (SELECT date(log.time), count(log.status) AS error_instance
         FROM log
            GROUP BY log.time
         ORDER BY error_instance desc) subquery1
      JOIN log
         ON date(log.time) = subquery1.date
    GROUP BY log.time
    HAVING status='404 NOT FOUND'
    ORDER BY error) ALIAS
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
GROUP BY log.time,error
ORDER BY log.time,error
```

this may fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately this just altered the error to read `aggregate functions are not allowed in the GROUP BY`. I get the feeling the calculation I am doing here: `count(log.status) * 100 / subquery1.error_instance AS error` is causing an issue. The column itself is an aggregation (so should not be allowed in GROUP BY, but it contains a reference to subquery column that **should be** in a GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

You are missing FROM clause before the subquery1

```
SELECT date(log.time), count(log.status) * 100 / subquery1.error_instance AS error FROM
  (SELECT date(log.time), count(log.status) AS error_instance
     FROM log
     WHERE status='404 NOT FOUND'
     GROUP BY log.time
     ORDER BY error_instance desc) subquery1
  JOIN log
     ON date(log.time) = subquery1.date
GROUP BY log.time
ORDER BY error
```

Comment: I've edited my original post. I had already included `FROM` in my query code so this was not the issue. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to have been attempting to perform the following calculation, in the select statement of my outer query:

`SELECT date(log.time), count(log.status) * 100 / subquery1.error_instance AS error`

The calculation was both an aggregation (count) and referenced a non-aggregation column from a subquery. Subsequently I got an error whether I used `error` in `GROUP BY` or not.

Instead, I took inspiration from @Gordon Linoff and created a table containing columns for both the `total_views` and `error_instances` then performed a simpler calculation in my outer query:

```
SELECT date_column, sum(sq2.error_instance::FLOAT * 100 / sq2.total_views) AS error
FROM
    (SELECT date(log.time) AS date_column, count(log.status) AS total_views, sq1.error_instance
    FROM
        (SELECT date(log.time) AS date_column, count(log.status) AS error_instance
        FROM log
        WHERE status='404 NOT FOUND'
        GROUP BY date(log.time)
        ORDER BY error_instance desc) sq1
    JOIN log on date(log.time) = sq1.date_row
    GROUP BY date(log.time), sq1.error_instance
    ORDER BY total_views desc) sq2
GROUP BY date_column
ORDER BY error desc
```